# Auto presenting XMLFile from the web

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rss

I want to take an RSS XML file from the web and present it my my ASP.NET page.

Is there a way to show it directly using a control of some sort and simply giving it the rss XML file web url?

Or there is no shortcut and i have to do it manually?

Comment: http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Presenting XML on ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10898/Introduction-to-XMLDataSource-control-in-ASP-NET-2)

This showes the solution.